# Connection attempt failed with "EAI_NODATA - No address associated with nodename" in filezilla

Tags: filezilla

I get the following error when I try to use Filezilla to connect to newly created domain:

> Connection attempt failed with "EAI_NODATA - No address associated with nodename"

I purchased domain name from "Bigrock.com" and purchased net space from "125mb.com". I have already changed the name servers in the cpanel of "bigrock" to the "125mb" name-servers. I have also uploaded the files in cpanel of "125mb".

When I open filezilla, I provide values as shown here:

host : koshh.co.in (this is the domain name I purchased)
username : *******
password : *******
Port : (default)

Comment: check if your domain nameserver is configured and you must use the IP address. usually at beginning of purchase the IP must be used in some hosting

Answer (score 24):

I was getting the same error trying to connect to host name in FileZilla:

```
ftp.news.domain.com
```

I changed to:

```
news.domain.com
```

And worked.

Comment: I didn't believed at first, because it was working for 7 to 8 month, and today it just stopped. So I removed the `ftp` from host name and now its working fine. Science? may be filezilla update or some thing. but above trick works. Thanks :)

Comment: This is slightly misleading. Actual error message is due to non-existent domain name, not due to address having `ftp.` in it. Using correct address fixes the problem. In some cases removing `ftp.` from the address may lead to correct DNS name but that's more luck than anything else ;)

Answer (score 16):

it simply means your domain name is not resolving, if domain is registered newly, then wait at least 4 to 8 hours (recommended 24-48 hours).

If you have been provided with IP address with your web hosting account details, then you can use IP address instead of domain name (ex. ftp.your-domain-name.xom)

If everything above is already tried out then you should contact your web hosting provider and your domain name registrar for further assistance.